# How do I get the slug of a custom taxonomy category of a post?

Tags: posts, categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, slug

In my template file, I loop through posts that are categorized  either *web*, *print*, or *marketing* in a custom taxonomy *portfolio*.

How do I echo the slug of each posts category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shouldn't be too hard!

```
$my_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio' );
if( $my_terms && !is_wp_error( $my_terms ) ) {
    foreach( $my_terms as $term ) {
        echo $term->slug;
    }
}
```